# Ошибка приема данных AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

Делаю регистрацию. С помощью AJAX.

В общем, PHP отсылает данные, их видно в консоли браузера.

Но JS не хочет их "съесть". Кто подскажет, в чем дело?

---

```
login.js:94 
Uncaught ReferenceError: dada is not defined
at Object.success (login.js:94)
at i (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
at A (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
```

---

```
  if (error == 0) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "loginator.php",
                data: {inlogin: login, inpass: pass},
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                dataType:'json',
                success:(function(data){
              if(data.loginsu) {    //94 строчка кода. на ней ошибка.

                  console.log(data.loginsu);
                  hello = dada.loginsu;
                  console.log(hello);
                  $('#ok').text(hello);

              }
                    // if(data.errorl){
                    //
                    // }
                }),
                beforesend: (inputnull()),
                complete: (clearInputform(myformlogin))
            });

            $('#Login').modal('hide');
            $('#SenksLogin').modal('show');
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#SenksLogin').modal('hide')
            }, 2000);


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тебе ошибка сама все говорит: `Uncaught ReferenceError: dada is not defined`

Проверь код внимательно, опечатка

```
hello = dada.loginsu;
```

Comment: Вот я олух) Спасибо бро)

Comment: Смотри на ошибки, они никогда не врут)) очень много времени экономит, если правильно ошибки читать и понимать, откуда что берется)